# Add Item to new List based on Key Value Pair

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

I'd like to loop through a list and add certain items to a new list if they meet the criteria. I have:

```
loans = [
    {
        "loan_price": 700,
        "remaining_months": 9,
        "repayment_interval": "monthly",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "loan_price": 500,
        "remaining_months": 13,
        "repayment_interval": "bullet",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "loan_price": 200,
        "remaining_months": 16,
        "repayment_interval": "bullet",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "loan_price": 900,
        "remaining_months": 16,
        "repayment_interval": "bullet",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
]


inexpensive_loans = []

#this is where my problem is

for item in loans:
    if loans.get("loan_price") <= 500:
        inexpensive_loans.append

print(f"{inexpensive_loans}")
```

How am I able to pull the value of loan price in the list?  Do I first have to get the value of loan_price before I run it through the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
inexpensive_loans = []

for item in loans:
    if item.get("loan_price") <= 500:
        inexpensive_loans.append(item)

print(f"{inexpensive_loans}")
```

Issues with your code

- You are not calling appending function `inexpensive_loans.append`
- You need to get the value from `item` (item.get("loan_price")) not `loans`

You can do the same thing using list comprehension as well.

```
inexpensive_loans = [item for item in loans if item.get("loan_price") <= 500]
```